# Pandas div using index

Tags: python, pandas

I am sometimes struggling a bit to understand pandas datastructures and it seems to be the case again. Basically, I've got:

- 1 pivot table, major axis being a serial number
- a Serie using the same index

I would like to divide each column of my pivot table by the value in the Serie using index to match the lines. I've tried plenty of combinations... without being successful so far :/

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['123', 1, 1, 3], ['456', 2, 3, 4], ['123', 4, 5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, rows=['A', 'B'], cols='C', values='D', fill_value=0)

serie = pd.Series([5, 5, 5], index=['123', '678', '345'])

pt.div(serie, axis='index')
```

But I am only getting NaN. I guess it's because columns names are not matching but that's why I was using index as the axis. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You say "using the same index", but they're not the same: `pt` has a multiindex, and `serie` only an index:

```
>>> pt.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'123', u'456'], [1, 2, 4]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1]],
           names=[u'A', u'B'])
```

And you haven't told the division that you want to align on the `A` part of the index.  You can pass that information using `level`:

```
>>> pt.div(serie, level='A', axis='index')
C        1   3    5
A   B              
123 1  0.6   0  0.0
    4  0.0   0  1.2
456 2  NaN NaN  NaN

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still struggling a bit with indexes actually. I did my calculation differently in the meantime but good to know about the _level_ keyword